# Cannot provide a value for property 'HandoverService' on type .NET 8

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

If I try to inject an interface in the `CreateHhandoverBase`, I get the error mentioned in the title when I navigate to the page.

I have already added the service to the `program.cs` just like in .NET 7.

CreateHandoverBase.razor.cs

```
    [Inject]
    protected IHandoverService? HandoverService { get; set;}
```

`Program.cs` in the client side:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();

// Add the new created services
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHandoverService, HandoverService>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere? Like github?

Comment: https://github.com/timtrommel/Univi2024/tree/master/Univi

Comment: It seems that repo is private. I can't access it.

Comment: I am sorry. It should be public now.